# Loading multiple Angular 2.0 SPA apps deployed separately

Tags: angular, single-page-application

We have scenario where in a Hosting App can have links to different SPA apps and all are deployed separately in their own domains. I think the picture below describes it better.

How can the below be implemented? We can share similar styles to the look and feel of all the apps feel the same. The user should be oblivious to the fact that he is interacting with multiple SPA apps.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are describing does not seems to be related with Angular. What you might be looking is creating an application which has a navigation menu and `iframe` which loads different applications into that.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: Thanks Madhu. What are the options if we dont want to iframe?

Comment: You will have to merge the code base that would be first, then you may bootstrap multiple angular application on the same page. But you wont be able to communicate between the applications, until you write your own framework to pass data along. Cheers!!

Comment: We dont want to merge the code base and thats the reason they are separate deployment components....